# module 'PIL.TiffTags' has no attribute 'IFD'

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, ocr, python-tesseract

When I use Pytesseract to recognize the text in an image , I am getting attribute error as

`module 'PIL.TiffTags' has no attribute 'IFD'`

What could be causing this?

This is the code I am running on google colab

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
img = cv2.imread("img.png")
img = cv2.resize(img, (400, 450))
cv2_imshow(img)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking your Pillow version as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53245643). That combined with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53672281) solution(to install Teserract) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall PIL library using `!pip install -U pillow` and restart the runtime